# Celery Error Email: can not receive emails celery

Tags: python, django, email, celery

I'm a python Django and celery beginner, I want to set up the celery on local. For now, I'm setting the error email for all the failure tasks. What I have done is this

Add these code to setting.py

```
CELERY_SEND_TASK_ERROR_EMAILS = True
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
ADMINS = (
    ('test', '...@....com'),
)
EMAIL_HOST='smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER='...@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD='...'
EMAIL_PORT=587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True`
```

Add this in tasks.py

```
@app.task(name="test_exception",error_whitelist=[])
```

Comment: Have checked your SMTP configuration and verified that you can send email using your SMTP settings?

Comment: @nixdaemon Thank you very much for your reply, did you mean add `EMAIL_USE_TLS = True` in the setting.py?

Comment: Yes if the SMTP requires you to use TLS. If you are on *nix environment you can test your SMTP via command line, if you are in windows environment you can use some gui email  utility (MTU) to test your SMTP connection. This would be the first step toward troubleshooting before checking the celery email settings.

Comment: @nixdaemon thanks! I use macos now, based on your comments, I could sent the emails through shell `from django.core.mail import send_mail`  `send_mail('Subject here', 'Here is the message.';    'from@gmail.com',['to@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)`, but still could not sent the emails about errors occurring during task. So I went to the tasks.py set the code like this `@app.task(send_error_emails = True)`, could you please help me to look at this?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Solved, I could receive the error emails now! I simply reorganized the setting.py with the settings in this post.

Comment: Which post are you talking about ?? "this" is not an hyperlink in your answer.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone trying to do this after version 4.0, `CELERY_SEND_TASK_ERROR_EMAILS` was apparently removed ([source](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/whatsnew-4.0.html#features-removed-for-simplicity)):

> Tasks no longer sends error emails. This also removes support for app.mail_admins, and any functionality related to sending emails.

One possible solution is adding email sending to the task decorator:

```
def shared_task_email(func):
    """
    Replacement for @shared_task decorator that emails admins if an exception is raised.
    """
    @wraps(func)
    def new_func(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
            subject = "Celery task failure"
            message = traceback.format_exc()
            mail_admins(subject, message)
            raise
    return shared_task(new_func)

@shared_task_email # instead of @shared_task
def test_task():
    raise Exception("Test exception raised by celery test_task")
```

Answer (score 0):

**In settings.py**

```
CELERY_SEND_TASK_ERROR_EMAILS = True
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
ADMINS = (
    ('test', '...@....com'),  # Admins syntax may vary by django version
)
EMAIL_HOST='smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER='...@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD='...'
EMAIL_PORT=587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

**Then in celery.py file, if you are making configuraton, then use this:**

```
app.conf.update(
    ADMINS = ('test', '...@....com'),
    CELERY_SEND_TASK_ERROR_EMAILS= True,
    ....
    ....
    )
```

**To test this code, check using this lines in shell:**

```
from app_name.celery import app
app.mail_admins('Subject', 'body', fail_silently=False)
```

> This must to send email to your Admins. If this work, then it will definately send email on failed task.

Comment: AttributeError: 'Celery' object has no attribute 'mail_admins'

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution to this is to handle Celery's `task_failure` signal. I published a ready-made implementation as a `pip` package.

To install, execute:

```
pip install celery-error-emails
```

Then edit your file `celery.py`. Typically, you'll have the lines

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proj.settings')
app = Celery('proj')
```

Add the following import above `app = ...`:

```
import celery_error_emails
```

That's it. From now on, you'll get emails like the following when a task fails:

```
Task your.module.task raised exception:

NameError("name 'typo' is not defined")

Task was called with args: [] kwargs: {}.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 412, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File ".../site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 704, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/project/main/tasks/_task.py", line 31, in new_func
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/project/main/tasks/__init__.py", line 71, in task
    typo
NameError: name 'typo' is not defined
```

The package is MIT licensed and available on GitHub at https://github.com/mherrmann/celery-error-emails.